# Where year filter Laravel collection

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Laravel collection with a "created_at" attribute, and I want to filter by year, like in eloquent:

```
$model->whereYear()
```

But in a collection.

Thx!

```
#attributes: array:10 [
        "id" => 720
        "created_at" => "2019-05-15 08:24:00"
        "updated_at" => "2019-05-15 08:24:00"
      ]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the Collections method [filter](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-filter) to only find those whose year matches your criteria:

```
$collection = Model::all();

$collection->filter(function ($value) {
    return $value->created_at->year === 2019; // assuming, that your timestamp gets converted to a Carbon object.
});
```

Comment: Yeah, that's a good solution too, I forgot completely Carbon in that case :(